# Unsupported Encoding Error in XMP Directory

Tags: c#, .net, metadata-extractor

I'd like to use Metadata extractor to read GPano XMP data from 360 photos.  I'm using photos from a Ricoh Theta S as my test image and I'm getting an error in the XmpDirectory.

> "Error processing XMP data: Unsupported Encoding"

My code is very basic,

```
        var dirs = ImageMetadataReader.ReadMetadata(filePath);
        var xmpDir = dirs.OfType<XmpDirectory>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (xmpDir?.XmpMeta != null)
        {
            foreach (var property in xmpDir.XmpMeta.Properties)
                Console.WriteLine($"Path={property.Path} Namespace={property.Namespace} Value={property.Value}");
        }
```

But the XmpMeta is always null.  If I use the debugger peek inside the XmpDirectory the about error is in _errorsList.

I know image has XMP data I want to access, If I open the image bytes in notepad++ I can locate the data in plaintext.

```
  <x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" xmptk="RICOH THETA S Ver1.62">
    <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
      <rdf:Description rdf:about="" xmlns:GPano="http://ns.google.com/photos/1.0/panorama/">
        <GPano:ProjectionType>equirectangular</GPano:ProjectionType>
        <GPano:UsePanoramaViewer>True</GPano:UsePanoramaViewer>
        <GPano:CroppedAreaImageWidthPixels>5376</GPano:CroppedAreaImageWidthPixels>
        <GPano:CroppedAreaImageHeightPixels>2688</GPano:CroppedAreaImageHeightPixels>
        <GPano:FullPanoWidthPixels>5376</GPano:FullPanoWidthPixels>
        <GPano:FullPanoHeightPixels>2688</GPano:FullPanoHeightPixels>
        <GPano:CroppedAreaLeftPixels>0</GPano:CroppedAreaLeftPixels>
        <GPano:CroppedAreaTopPixels>0</GPano:CroppedAreaTopPixels>
        <GPano:PoseHeadingDegrees>157.5</GPano:PoseHeadingDegrees>
        <GPano:PosePitchDegrees>3.9</GPano:PosePitchDegrees>
        <GPano:PoseRollDegrees>-11.5</GPano:PoseRollDegrees>
      </rdf:Description>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </x:xmpmeta>
```

I'm using Metadata-Extractor 2.0.0 from nuget.

Comment: I forgot to clarify, I'm using .jpg images default settings on the Ricoh Theta S.

Comment: Can you get a full stack trace for the exception? Perhaps you could [open an issue](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor-dotnet/issues/new) and attach a sample image to it.